# CQ5 startup issue

Tags: aem

```
I have mac 10.11.1

When I start cq5-author-4502.jar, the CQ5 starts and takes about 20 minutes     
and after that it opens up browser at localhost:4502/ at both chrome and   
firefox saying :
```

---

```
Service Unavailable

AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate request.
```

---

```
**If i turn off the Wi-Fi, then it works fine.**


I get the following initial most error in the error.log file located at
/Users/Singh/Desktop/CQ/crx-quickstart/logs/error.log

*ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl failed   
to start Repository: Unable to register data store in cluster.   
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to register data store in cluster.
```

*
*
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create a listener on any of the
    following ports: [8088, 8089, 8090, 8091, 8092, 8093], and could not connect
    to another cluster node

---

```
Following are the contents of /etc/hosts file :
```

---

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

::1             localhost
```

---

```
Following is my computer name :
Computers on your local network can access your computer at:
SFOLNAVCHETANSMAC01.local
```

---

```
I have java 1.6


Following is my bash profile :
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH


export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"
```

---

I have tried almost all the solutions I could find on gooogle.

Any help ?

Thanks.
   ~NS

Answer (score 1):

They way I fixed it : I turned off the Wifi, started the localhost CQ, and once localhost worked, I turned on the Wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have got some cluster related properties in your aem setup. If it's a standalone instance you can remove all the cluster related files from your crx-quickstart folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you tell me what directories would be that ?

Comment: Not sure which version of AEM you are using but till 5.6.1 the cluster related configuration used to be in "crx-quickstart/repository/"